# document.cookie work around in Chrome

Tags: javascript, html, google-chrome, cookies

The following code writes a cookie. However, in chrome `document.cookie` does not seem to work. Is there any work arounds? I need to set this cookie in all browsers.

Do I  have anyother options?

```
//Cookie Functions
function createCookie(name, value, days) {
    var expires = "";
    if (days) {
        var date = new Date();
        date.setTime(date.getTime() + (days * 24 * 60 * 60 * 1000));
        expires = "; expires=" + date.toGMTString();
    }
    var cookie_string = name + "=" + value + expires;
    //document.cookie =  + "; path=/";
    cookie_string += "; path=" + (cookiePath.length ? cookiePath : '/');
    cookie_string += "; domain=" + (cookieDomain.length ? cookieDomain : window.location.hostname);
    if ( cookieSecure ) {
        cookie_string += "; secure";
    }
    document.cookie = cookie_string;
    alert("Your Cookie : " + document.cookie);
}
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When you access this script from local which does not work in chrome, eg:-

```
c:\yourFolder\yourScript
```

If you access this script from remote server then it does work. eg:-

```
loalhost\yourFolder\yourScript
```

Here `localhost` is remote server / web server.

You can put your script into `htdocs` of `xampp` folder for experiment.

[**XAMPP**](https://www.apachefriends.org/index.html) is a software package of php, mysql, apache server. Which is work as remote/web server in your case.